# Does redis bind to CPU cores automatically?

Tags: redis

I have a server with 32 logical cores(16 physical cores and hyper-thread enabled) and have 8 redis instances on it. It seems that only 16 cores, id from 0 to 7 and 16 to 23, are used and other 16 cores are idled. It shows the cpu affinity mask for any redis process is FFFFFFFF(from taskset -p pid).

So I wonder that the cpu affinity has been set automatically in redis?

Thanks

Leo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NO, Redis doesn't set CPU affinity**. I think you misunderstand the output of the [taskset](https://linux.die.net/man/1/taskset) command.

The affinity mask you got, i.e. `FFFFFFFF`, means that the process might be running on any of the processors. And that's the default behavior. You can test it by starting a process that doesn't set CPU affinity, e.g. `vim xxx.conf`, and use `taskset` to check the mask. It should also return `FFFFFFFF`.

In order to make the process running on a specific CPU, you can run the following command: `taskset -pc 0 process_id`, i.e. running on the `0th` processor.

Comment: Yes. I understand FFFFFFFF means the process may be scheduled on any CPU to run. I just observed the instances are always scheduled on CPU0 to 7 and 16 to 23. It seems they are never run on CPU8 to 15 and CPU24 to 31. Today I find my server has two physical CPUs. From /proc/cpuinfo, I find CPU0(Logical core) to 7 and CPU16 to 23 belong to the physical CPU 0. and other cores belong to the physical CPU1. So the CentOS7.1(kernel 3.10) is very smart to schedule the redis process.

Comment: Otherwise, I have another  same server with Cento 6.6(kernel 2.6.32). Unfortunely, It always schedule the 8 instances to run on CPU0 and CPU16 and the other 30 cores are always idle. Is there some fault in the CentOS 6.6 about this?

Comment: @LeoWong I can only confirm that Redis doesn't set CPU affinity. I think you should ask another question on process schedule with other tags. :)